# How can we use web api services in other projects like we use in wcf services in other projects?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

my question is when we create project in wcf after completion we can use the project service in other project too by writing just local address in references so is it possible same thing in web api projects??

Comment: This is a badly written question. Can you give us examples of what you are trying to do and perhaps some code? At the moment no one will be able to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: thanks for reply i have solved my question.